# The sqlite query using CTE and update clause gives error while preparing statement but executes succcessfully on sqlite browser

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, common-table-expression, sqlite-browser

I am executing this query :

```
WITH T_item AS 
    (
    SELECT uuid, field_updated_at 
    FROM item 
    WHERE uuid IN 
        ( 
            SELECT DISTINCT item_uuid 
            FROM itemfield 
            WHERE updated_at <= 0 OR value_updated_at <= 0 
        )
    ) 
    
UPDATE itemfield 
SET updated_at = T_item.field_updated_at, 
    value_updated_at = T_item.field_updated_at 
FROM T_item 
WHERE itemfield.item_uuid = T_item.uuid;
```

This query gives error when sqlite3_prepare_v2 is used to prepare the statement in the code :
SQL Error :  near "FROM": syntax error

However, it executes successfully on sqlite browser installed in my device on the same database.

What can be the reason about the same?

Comment: My guess: the C++ version is using a string literal for that SQL command, and that literal has a typo. Like an extra semicolon or an extra invisible character. To be sure: use a raw string literal (`R"(...)"`) and copy paste a working command into the C++ source.

Comment: Hi @prapin, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work out with the raw string too.

Comment: I bet your program is using a much older version of sqlite than the other program is.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, my sqliteDB Browser has version 3.12.2 and my source code includes sqlite3.h having version 3.28.0.